# The unique expression for elements of function field of $X=\{ y^2-x^3-x^2=0\}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

This is from the Exercise 2 of Chapter I, section 3 in Shafaravich's book. The question is that every element in $k(X)$ can be written as $u(x)+v(x)y$ for some rational functions $u(x),v(x) \in k[x,x^{-1}]$.

My attempt is below; Since $y^{2}-x^{2}-x^{3}$ is prime (Use Eisenstein criterion by thinking $k[x]$ as PID and the prime element $x+i$ in $k[x]$ such that $x+i$ cannot divides $x^{2}+x^{3}$ (one can check by constructing the quotient), we know $k[X] = k[x,y]/(y^{2}-x^{2}-x^{3})$, i.e., the coordinate ring is $X$. Thus, any element in $k[X]$ can be written as $f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(x)y$ for some polynomials $f_{1},f_{2} \in k[x]$. Thus any elements in $k(X)$ is of a form $(f_{1}+f_{2}y)/(g_{1}+g_{2}y)$.

However, I'm stuck at this point. How can we change the form $(f_{1}+f_{2}y)/(g_{1}+g_{2}y)$ into $u(x)+v(x)y$? Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean $u(x),v(x) \in k(x)$, which is just because $k(x)[y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$  is a quadratic extension of $k(x)$.

Comment: I think you need to insist that $u(x), v(x)$ come from $k(x)$ as opposed to $k[x,x^{-1}]$. In that case the usual trick of multiplying both the numerator and the denominator by $g_1-g_2y$ works. Remember that in $k[X]$ you have $y^2=x^3+x^2$. It is the exact same process you rationalize the denominator of a number like $(2+\sqrt2)/(3+\sqrt2)$. Only this time you have the abstract $y$ instead of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: About $u(x),v(x)\in k[x,x^{-1}]$: $k[x,x^{-1},y]$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra whereas the function field contains $k(x)$ which is not finitely generated.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, @reuns Oh you right. The expression in the book is ``$u(x),v(x)$  are arbitrary rational functions of $x$" so I can insist that they are in $k(x)$. Thank you very much!